# Add "Show all products" to all product categories that have child categories on default Woocommerce listing widget

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to add some custom feature to the default Woocommerce product category listing widget. The widget is working fine, but I need to add a "Show all products" list element to all categories that have child category list element. The "Show all products" list element is needed to show all products of the parent category.

Example:

- Category A

  - Show All Products
  - Category A.1
  - Category A.2
- Category B

  - Show All Products
  - Category B.1
  - Category B.2
  - Category B.3
- Category C
- Category D

  - Show All Products
  - Category D.1
  - Category D.2
  - Category D.3

Comment: Create your own widget. Copy the current one for base and modify to your needs. Google how to create widget there are many examples.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

here is an solution what I just created and it woks for me:

```js
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.wc-block-product-categories-list-item').each(function() {
    var $parentItem = $(this);
    var $subCategories = $parentItem.find('.wc-block-product-categories-list');

    if ($subCategories.length > 0) {
      var parentLink = $parentItem.find('a').attr('href');
      var $showAllLink = $('<li class="wc-block-product-categories-list-item show-all-link"><a href="' + parentLink + '">Show All Products</a></li>');

      $showAllLink.on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        window.location.href = parentLink;
      });

      $subCategories.prepend($showAllLink);
    }
  });
});
</script>
```